# How can I save a method for later, stubbing it for a period of time?

Tags: grails, groovy, metaprogramming, metaclass

I'm writing a selenium-aid for a web application, and for one of the functions, I'm stubbing away the responses of a grails service. Is there any way to persist the methods for later, such that I can turn the service "back on"? The idea is that my test-aid code can be completely separated from production code, and no test-aids leak into the real service layer.

This works fine for turning the service "off", but getting it back on is an issue.

I'm doing this:

```
myService.metaClass.method1 = {true}
myService.metaClass.method2 = {false}
```

I tried just storing `myService.metaClass.method1`, but attempting to set it later just leaves the method stub.

How can I store `method1` and `method2` for later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a reference with `getMetaMethod`, e.g.

```
def oldMethod1 = MyService.metaClass.getMetaMethod('method1')

MyService.metaClass.method1 = { -> true }

def myService = ...

def realValue = oldMethod.invoke(myService)
```

Comment: MyService.metaClass.method1 = oldMethod1 doesn't seem to change the invocation of method1, however. Should it?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with how ExpandoMetaClass would work with a MetaMethod, but this should work: `MyService.metaClass.method1 = { -> oldMethod1.invoke(delegate) }`

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best way, but it is **a** way.

```
if (originalServiceMethods.isEmpty()) {
    originalServiceMethods = myService.metaClass.getMethods()
}

myService.metaClass.invokeMethod = {name, args ->
        def newMethods = [:]
        newMethods["method1"] = {true}
        newMethods["method2"] = {false}
        if (name in newMethods.keySet()) {
            return newMethods[name].call()
        }
        else {
            return myService.metaClass.getMetaMethod(name, args)
        }
}
```

...

```
if( !originalServiceMethods.isEmpty() ){
        myService.metaClass.invokeMethod = {name, args ->
            MetaMethod method = originalServiceMethods.find { it.name == name }
            method.invoke(myService, args)
        }
}
```